# Flutter project always showing "Flutter launching" on IQOO Z7s device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter project when running it on my IQOO Z7s device using VS Code. In debug mode, the app builds successfully, but it continuously displays "Flutter launching" on the device screen. Additionally, changes made to the code do not reflect in real-time using hot reload; I have to stop and restart the project to see any modifications.

Interestingly, this problem doesn't occur on other devices, where everything works fine. I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue specifically on the IQOO Z7s device.